# Parallel calls to ListBlobs in Azure storage don't result in performance improvement

Tags: asynchronous, f#, azure-blob-storage, parallel.foreach

I have code (written in F# but I believe it the choice of language doesn't matter) that calls ListBlobs for each entry in the list of Azure blob directories, about 50 entries in total. The total time for all calls is about 20 seconds. Here's how the original code looks:

```
enumerateDirectories container
|> Seq.map (fun x -> listBlobs x)
|> Seq.concat
```

The function "listBlobs" is a simple wrapper around Azure blob storage ListBlobs method. Since blob listings are independent from each other, I tried running them asynchronously:

```
enumerateDirectories container
|> Seq.map (fun x ->
            async {
                 printfn "listBlobs %s" x 
                 return listBlobs x 
            })
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> Seq.concat
```

But the execution time didn't improve at all. Then I changed F# async workflow with the parallel sequence call from the pseq module:

```
enumerateDirectories container
|> PSeq.map (fun x -> listBlobs x)
|> Seq.concat
```

This improved the execution time so it took only half of what it used to be. Still, it takes about 10 seconds comparing to a less than a second for a single ListBlob call. I wonder why. Shouldn't calls to ListBlobs execute concurrently so the total time would be comparable with the single call time plus some overhead?

Comment: This is likely IO-bound, and likely on the server-side.

Comment: Is listBlobs itself async or returning a Task? If not, async won't help, surely?

Comment: ListBlobs is not async, however multiple ListBlobs are parallelized so it should not matter that each individual call is sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel queries may not gain more performance especially for scan operations like ListBlobs. Such operations should be limited and not depended upon for latency sensitive operations as the performance is proportional to the number of objects and is executed with lower priority when it requires more resources than allowed.

That said, you can look at storage analytics to ensure all calls were actually dispatched concurrently and the difference between e2e latency and server latency is minimal.

Check out the following links for more helpful information:

- http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist/
- http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not aware of that.